# How do I use auto complete in a multi line column

Tags: multiple-lines-of-text

Is it possible to use autocomplete in a Multi-line text column? 
I have a list of addresses that I want to reference using autocomplete but I can only get it to work in a single line column which messes with the formatting when I insert the info into a word template I am using for invoices. Below is what I use for the single line. Can this be changed to work with a multi-line text column

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "SourceListName",
            sourceColumn: "SourceColumnName",
            columnName: "DestinationColumnName",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can this be changed to work with a multi-line text column?**

As a short answer: **No**,

The `SPServices.SPAutocomplete` doesn't support `Multi-line text` column, it only supports a `single line of text` column to provide values from a SharePoint list.

**For more details**, check [SPAutocomplete function](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/value-added/SPAutocomplete.html)